# Use whole swift code in Objective-C project (with two AppDelegate classes)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, appdelegate

I have one swift project with few functions. I want to use all of that classes in my Objective-C code. I have successfully added all of that swift classes to my Objective-C project. But as some of the function were depending on appdelegate file of swift, I am not able to access that functions as there can't be two `UIResponder` AppDelegate file in a single project. Is there any way to access that.
Or is there any way that I can convert my swift project to single library or framework and access it in Objective-C code.

Thanks in advance.

Aakil

Comment: Why don't you merge these two AppDelegate files ?

Comment: because the code in swift file is dependent on appdel file of swift

Comment: Then rewrite your code. Shouldn't take long.